# Can a context-senstive gramma contains production rule $cB\rightarrow Bc$?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Some textbook show that the grammar $G=(N,T,P,S)$ below belongs to context-senstive grammars:

1. S->aSBC
2. S->abc
3. cB->Bc
4. bG->bb

where N={S,B}, T={a,b,c}.

I am confused by the fact that the production rule cB->Bc cannot satisfy the definition of a CSG. So, why is the above grammar belongs to CSG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is not unexpected. That grammar is not a context-sensitive grammar in its usual strict sense.

However, that grammar can be considered as a context-sensitive grammar in some situations. [The Wikipedia entry on context-sensitive grmmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Formal_definition) reads the following.

> Some definitions of a context-sensitive grammar only require that for any production rule of the form $u \to v$, the length of $u$ shall be less than or equal to the length of $v$. This seemingly weaker requirement is in fact [weakly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_equivalence_%28formal_languages%29), see [Noncontracting grammar#Transforming into context-sensitive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar#Transforming_into_context-sensitive_grammar).

You may want to double check the definition of CFG and exposition thereafter in the textbook you mentioned.